# Changing column datatype from Timestamp to datetime64

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy-ndarray, python-datetime

I have a database I'm reading from excel as a pandas dataframe, and the dates come in Timestamp `dtype`, but I need them to be in `np.datetime64`, so that I can make calculations.

I am aware that the function `pd.to_datetime()` and the `astype(np.datetime64[ns])` method do work. However, I am unable to update my dataframe to yield this datatype, for whatever reason, using the code mentioned above.

I have also tried creating an acessory dataframe from the original one, with just the dates that I wish to update the typing, converting it to `np.datetime64` and plugging it back onto the original dataframe:

```
dfi = df['dates']
dfi = pd.to_datetime(dfi)
df['dates'] = dfi
```

But still it doesn't work. I have also tried updating values one by one:

```
arr_i = df.index
for i in range(len(arr_i)):
    df.at[arri[l],'dates'].to_datetime64()
```

**Edit**
The root problem seems to be that the `dtype` of the column gets updated to `np.datetime64`, but somehow, when getting single values from within, they still have the `dtype = Timestamp`

Does anyone have a suggestion of a workaround that is fairly fast?

Comment: Why doesn't `df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])` work?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by doesn't work? What is that output or error message?

Comment: The thing is, they work. There is no error message, the dataframe just does not get updated with the typing.

Comment: What dtype do you get for the column? "It doesn't work" doesn't really give us any information when we dont have the data to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Is there a difference between column `dtype` and the `dtype` of the data inside? If so, when I print the acessory dataframe, it is an `np.datetime64`, but when I try to get individual values from within the column, I get `Timestamp`.
I wil update the information on the question with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas tries to standardize all forms of datetimes by [storing them as NumPy datetime64[ns] values](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py#L2092) when you assign them to a DataFrame. But when you try to access individual datetime64 values, [they are returned as Timestamps](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py#L2179).

[There is a way](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18305) to prevent this automatic conversion from happening however: Wrap the list of values in a Series of dtype `object`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# create some dates, merely for example
dates = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=10)
# convert the dates to a *list* of datetime64s
arr = list(dates.to_numpy())
# wrap the values you wish to protect in a Series of dtype object.
ser = pd.Series(arr, dtype='object')

# assignment with `df['datetime64s'] = ser` would also work
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamps': dates,
                   'datetime64s': ser})

df.info()
# <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
# RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9
# Data columns (total 2 columns):
# timestamps     10 non-null datetime64[ns]
# datetime64s    10 non-null object
# dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(1)
# memory usage: 240.0+ bytes

print(type(df['timestamps'][0]))
# <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>

print(type(df['datetime64s'][0]))
# <class 'numpy.datetime64'>
```

---

But beware! Although with a little work you can circumvent Pandas' automatic conversion mechanism,
it may not be wise to do this. First, converting a NumPy array to a list is usually a sign you are doing something wrong, since it is bad for performance. Using `object` arrays is a bad sign since operations on object arrays are generally much much slower than equivalent operations on arrays of native NumPy dtypes.

You may be looking at an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) -- it may be more fruitful to  find a way to (1)
work with Pandas Timestamps instead of trying to force Pandas to return NumPy
datetime64s or (2) work with datetime64 array-likes (e.g. Series of NumPy arrays) instead of handling values individually (which causes the coersion to Timestamps).

Comment: I understand, and it makes sense. I should be able to preprocess my dataset well enough to make calculations with the whole columns, I guess it's the way pandas was supposed to be used. Thank you for the explanation.